# How to create a git patch with the parent SHA so it can serve as an archive?

Tags: git, git-patch

Imagine I'm working on an exploratory branch on a git repo and it only has one commit. I decide that my work is not needed any time soon, and I don't want to create a branch/tag. In fact, I'd like to throw away the changes, but just in case I ever need them again, I'd like to save a patch.

For purposes of this post, imagine I only have one change that I want to archive:

```
* 040cc7c   (HEAD, ExperimentalBranch) This is where the experiment is
* a29ceb7   (master) This is the main branch
...
```

My proposed archive solution is as follows:

1. Create a patch of commit `040cc7c`.
2. Archive the patch file somewhere for longterm storage.
3. Delete the `ExperimentalBranch` from the repo.

So far everything seems great, until years later when I might want to restore the patch. It will likely reference files/lines that are incompatible and not be able to be applied. To solve this, I could check out the patch's parent SHA and apply it there.

Therefore my proposed unarchive solution is as follows:

1. Checkout SHA `a29ceb7`.
2. Apply the patch.

The only problem is that when I create the patch, I see that it contains SHA `040cc7c`, but does not mention `a29ceb7` anywhere. It could be very hard for me to figure out the parent of `040cc7c` years after I created the patch. Furthermore, because I deleted the branch years earlier, I wouldn't expect there to be a git command that could help me discover the parent.

When creating a patch, is there a way to ensure that its parent SHA is included in the file as well?

---

My current workaround is to rename the patch to include the parent's SHA, but this can be easy to forget, and is more manual.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to delete the branch, but if you really want to store the patch somewhere else, you may do

```
git format-patch --base HEAD^ HEAD^
```

so that the parent (base) is written in the patch

example:

```
$ git format-patch --base HEAD^ HEAD^ 
0001-test.patch
$ cat 0001-test.patch 
From 057ff8fa3ba485abeb69156e9717570ad483d52c Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Dispeakable me <Dispeakable.me@whatever.io>
Date: Sat, 27 Mar 2021 09:47:23 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] test

---
 test.cpp | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

diff --git a/test.cpp b/test.cpp
index 6f4ed1e..1ef4295 100644
--- a/test.cpp
+++ b/test.cpp
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 
+
 #include <list>
 
 class Semaphore {

base-commit: b50a780230e2f3f2be8bf6ad3797de272cafba5c
-- 
2.26.3
```

and you can check the parent sha1:

```
$ git cat-file -p  HEAD
tree 5c03e768250fe7fe94d8ba0454feae422abd6aac
parent b50a780230e2f3f2be8bf6ad3797de272cafba5c
author Dispeakable me <Dispeakable.me@whatever.io> 1616834843 +0100
committer Dispeakable me <Dispeakable.me@whatever.io> 1616834843 +0100

test
```